# Bash check file existence with file expansion

Tags: bash

I want to check if there is a file matching a given pattern exists in the target directory, thus write

```
data_dir="/home"
sample="HT001"
r1Pattern=".R1.gz"
shopt -s nullglob

if [ -f ${data_dir}/${sample}*combined${r1Pattern} ]
then
  ./myscript
fi
```

There is NO `/home/HT001_combined.R1.gz` exist. But this code kept telling me file exists. Is there anything I missed?

Thanks.

Comment: What does `file ${data_dir}/${sample}*combined${r1Pattern}` show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of `nullglob` mode. Since the file does not exist, the glob expands to nothing. And, for an empty arguement, `-f` will return true if you use `[`:

```
$ empty=
$ [ -f $empty ] && echo yes
yes
```

You can solve your problem by using the `bash` `[[` instead:

```
$ [[ -f $empty ]] && echo yes
```

`[[` generally provides more predictable and friendly behavior.

EDIT:

Yeah you are right, It seems that actually the glob is not evaluated when using `[[`.  The way that comes to mind to do it is more like:

```
f=(${data_dir}/${sample}*combined${r1Pattern})
if (( ${#f[@]} == 1 )) && [[ -f ${f[0]} ]]
then
    # ...
fi
```

This expands the glob into an array, makes sure there is exactly one result, and verifies that it is a regular file.

Comment: Technically `-f` isn't returning true. It isn't being seen (by `[`) as a test argument but rather as the string to test with `-n`. Also without nullglob this would have failed in other interesting ways.

Comment: Also `[[` is bash-specific, just for the record.

Comment: I changed [ to [[, now if there is a /home/HT001_combined.R1.gz exists, the code tells me no such file.